# Apply iconv to all of the files in a directory

Tags: command-line, bash, utf-8

While trying to convert a collection of .srt files:

```
iconv -f cp1256 -t utf-8 directory/* > target/*
```

it converts all of the 22 files in the directory to one file in the target directory called *. I want the processed files to appear separately in the target directory. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cd path-to-source-directory
find . -name "*.srt" -exec iconv -f CP1256 -t UTF-8 {} -o path-to-destination-directory/{} +
```

Example:

If source-directory is called SOURCE and destination-directory is called DESTINATION and both directories are located on the desktop, then path-to-source-directory is `~/Desktop/SOURCE` and path-to-destination-directory is `~/Desktop/DESTINATION`

Comment: find: Only one instance of {} is supported with -exec ... + :(